# How do I stream large amount of vector3 fast from disk in real-time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a project in Unity where I need to render large amounts of data stored on disk. The data includes root transforms for all the players in a soccer match. Later on we will also get access to bone transforms.

The code I inherited from the old developers basically serializes the data to a custom file format containing "chunked" streams of positional data for *players* and the *ball*. The *chunks* are divided up according to a set duration of 1000 ms. With my (very) limited knowledge, I cannot see the performance benefits of dividing the data into chunks in a binary format. Would it not be more performant just to use some buffer and read in a subset of the data?

So far I only read about the topic to understand concepts of related to optimizing memory and IO. But I have a hard time understanding what topic to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some possible advantages to chunking this kind of data

1. It may allow for indexing, to allow you to directly jump to a certain point in time. You could also do this for each frame, but you probably do not *need* better resolution than 1s. This may be possible to do without an index, but that require each frame to contain exactly the same amount of data.
2. It may improve IO performance to do fewer but larger read/writes. But this will probably depend on the IO system, buffering etc. So I would test this before concluding anything.
3. It may allow for compression. A common compression strategy is to store differences instead of last values. But if you want to jump to a specific time you need some type of chunks that can be independently decompressed.
4. My guess is that this type of data should not be all that taxing. My guess would be somewhere around 1MB/s, not something that should cause a problem for either the CPU or an SSD. However, it should be possible to reduce the amount of data drastically by being a bit smarter. For example by storing input, or when animations starts.

If you are concerned about performance the most important thing is to profile and or benchmark your solution. So that you know:

1. Is it a problem?
2. What specifically is the problem?
3. Did my fix actually improve things?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I was unclear, I think chunking is a good idea, but what I don't understand is making the chunks beforehand. Would it be bad to just use something like Seek() to just read intervals (similar to the chunks) of a continuous stream of the data? That way I can also dynamically decide the size of my chunks instead of being limited to a predefined size. :) I am merely asking because I assume chunking beforehand has some benefits since the previous developer decided to do that instead.

Comment: @MikkelMogensen Using Seek should work perfectly fine, as long as you have some way to know the exact address to seek to. A kind of assumed that was what you meant with "chunking". One technique I like is to use a zip-archive to store related data. That way the user has only a single file, but you can layout different data blocks however you want inside the file.

Comment: Maybe I am just not understanding binary formatting correctly. But I assume every frame containing player position and ball position has the same amount of bytes. So if I know the data layout I can calculate the offsets needed to read every single frame.

(Edit: This was a continuation of my first comment, but you answered very quickly, haha)

Comment: Ok, thanks :) the feedback was very valuable

Comment: @MikkelMogensen You can use fixed sizes blocks, and just calculate the indices, but this *may* be fragile. note that "binary formatting" might mean 1) using BinaryFormatter, 2) using binaryReader/writer, 3) using some third party binary serialization library. #1 is horrible, and should be avoided at all cost. #2 is ok, but probably inflexible. #3 my preference. I would probably use a protobuf .net for serialization, and store 'chunks' inside a zip-archive. That should give fairly good flexibility in case you want to update the format.

Comment: Ok, I was referring to (2). I agree that it might be inflexible, but on the other hand, our custom file format also specifies a version number, so if we want to change how it is serialized later, maybe it's not so bad. I never thought about option (3), but that's really interesting. I will do some research on it :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's do the math:

`22 players` + `ball` makes `23 x Vector3` = `69` (nice! :'D) `float`s
= binary `69 x 4b` = `276b`.

If you also include orientation and take `Quaternion` to be save it is additional `22 x Quaternion` = `88 x float` = `88 x 4b` = `352b` per frame.

Making a total of `628 b per frame`.

Your frames are only once a second (1000ms) so let's now say you load `90 Minutes` of play aka

```
90 x 60 x 628 b  
= 3,391,200 b
= 3,312 Kb
= 3.2 Mb
```

that would only make about `3.2Mb` of data for an entire soccer match.

=> I would also rather load/parse it chunkwise / even load the entire data at the beginning completely into memory to avoid any FileIO hickups with stream loading frame-wise.

Even if you have bones later and 20 times the data I would still load those 64 Mb into memory. Every modern device should be able to handle that. And as mentioned this has other advantages like jumping to a certain time frame etc

Comment: I actually have frames every few milliseconds but they are grouped in 1000 ms chunks (the old developers decision). I think there are at least 25 frames per 1000 ms chunk. I know it sounds weird  but it was made for the purpose of quickly scrubbing the timeline on 1 second intervals. However, as mentioned in other comments, I would rather not have the file itself contain chunks.

Comment: Even with 25 frames per chunk, the file ends up being only 77 Mb for one of the matches I serialized (without skeletal data). It will definitely still fit in RAM. I guess the problem is not so much RAM memory, but how to efficiently stream the data to multiple entities in Unity efficiently. I guess a lot of the overhead is simply how Unity renders skinned meshes, and I would probably have to look into DOTS for higher performance.

Comment: And sorry I can't upvote you even though I would like to. I'm new to StackOverflow